# How to wait for specified time in critical section locked by ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantlock

I need to stop thread somehow for 1 sec while thread is in critical section locked by `ReentrantLock`.

My code is :

```
public class Lock implements Runnable {
    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is running !");
            lock.wait(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lock lock = new Lock();
        Thread thread = new Thread(lock);

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

When I call `lock.wait(1000)` in run() method it throws `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Why is this exception if I obtained monitor by `lock.lock()` method?

The same happens when I call `super.wait(1000)` instead of `lock.wait(1000)`.

Comment: This is not what `lock.wait` does. `wait` atomically releases the `lock` and suspends the thread. This is part of the [`wait`/`notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) API - it is inherited from `Object` and not part of `Lock`. In order to call `wait` you **must** own the monitor on the object - i.e. you must be `synchronized` on it. You are looking for `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Why occurs `IllegalMonitorStateException`?

Comment: Because you are in an illegal monitor state, and that's an exception. Read about `synchronized` blocks and `wait`/`notify`. This has nothing to do with `Lock` and you shouldn't be using it here.

Comment: synchronized is about object's implicit monitor and ReentrantLock is about mutual exclusive access to resource.

Comment: @Volodia as @Boris said: if you want to sleep use `Thread.sleep()` if you insist on misusing wait you have to write it as `long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); synchronized (lock) { while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 1000) { lock.wait(1000); } }`

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception when calling `lock.wait(1000)` inside the lock b/c you haven't got the object locked in the right way.  It's a thing.

```
synchronized(object) {
  object.wait(1000);
}
```

That works b/c you have the `object`'s monitor locked.  `ReentrantLock.lock()` works in a different way.  All is not lost!  You can use `Thread.sleep()` or `LockSupport.parkNanos()` to put your thread to sleep inside the critical section.

If you need to handle spurious wakeup, you'll want a loop.

```
long waitStart = System.nanoTime();
long waitTime = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1);
do {
  LockSupport.parkNanos(waitTime);
  waitTime = waitTime - (System.nanoTime() - waitStart);
} while(waitTime > 0);
```

Or some variation of the above.

Good luck.

Comment: i think removing the `waitTime = wait...` and `} while (System.nanoTime() - waitStart < waitTime);` would be much easier to understand.